# Set Cookie to redirect if page has already been visited

Tags: javascript, html, flash, cookies, web

Before Entering my site, I have a flash intro that is played, and now, I want to know how I can make it so that if the intro page has already been seen, that it does not show it next time, until the cookie expires or is deleted.

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework like jQuery?

Comment: No, it's just a page with a flash movie, you can see it here: [link](mychoiceelectronics.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use javascript to read and write cookies by using javascript code and make your logic in javascript function i.e.

```
function GetSetCookie() {
            var version = getCookie("version");
            if (version != null && version != "") {
                if (version == 'full') {
                    version = 'text';
                }
                else {
                    version = 'full';
                }
            }
            else {
                version = 'full';
            }
            setCookie("version", version, 365);
            window.top.location.reload();
        }
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + "; path=/";
        }
        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
```

By using these function you can read and write cookies 
and mke you login according to this and use

```
location.top.href = "http://www.xyz.com/";
```

for redirecting a page URL.....

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will try this in a bit and report back later if I have any issues

Comment: So how exactly do I use this? I'm not very familiar with java script, do I just paste this into the header of my html file, adding `<script type="text/javascript">` before and `</script>` after? and where do I put the `location.top.href`?

Comment: Yeah I got it, I thought I had replied back? weird
edit: I remember now, I was having a bit of issues with it, that I had solved here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374847/expiration-of-cookie-not-working-is-this-wrong/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Local Shared Object functionality of Flash player to read user preferences. Store a Boolean value and check for it every time the movie is initiated. For more on LSO or (Flash Cookies)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

It's supported all the way through flash player 6 and AS2/3

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to keep it separate from the flash, which is why I will use the code provided by Gaurav.

Answer (score 0):

Then you must set the cookie on the client side after or during the intro, via Javascript for example, and then look for that cookie whenever a request is received by the server. If it exists, alter your response in a way that does not include the intro or at least stops it from playing.